# Using default command in Eclipse RCP 4.X

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I want to use some default commands that the Eclipse Framework provide for us. For example I want to use a default command (Handler) which are implementing the Copy/Paste/Cut etc. mechanism.

I found some information, that eclipse define some default keys like these:

- Save: org.eclipse.ui.file.save
- Save All: org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll
- Undo: org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo
- Copy: org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy

Now I have use these keys to define some commands etc. in the Application.e4xmi file.

[image: Application.e4xmi Command]

[image: Application.e4xmi Command Category]

[image: Application.e4xmi MenuHandleItem]

But this configuration is not working, did I have miss some config setting, or did I make something complete wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Eclipse e4 application does not define default handlers for anything. You must provide handlers for everything.

The commands you mention (such as `org.eclipse.ui.file.save`) have predefined ids because some things in the Eclipse code reference them by the id.

You may see references to 'default handlers' but this will be talking about Eclipse 3.x style command handling.

Comment: did you know some ressources, where I can find some examples. Till now, I find only ressources about save/saveAll. But nothing about copy/cut/paste etc. I have use the context spy for the eclipse app, but I don't find a concrete handler implementation?

Comment: The Eclipse app has lots of 3.x compatibility code so it is probably handled in that and won't be useful in a 4.x app. I don't know of any e4 examples for copy/paste but the basic SWT Clipboard, Transfer is still usable.